# Showing $3<\pi<2\sqrt{3}$ using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

First of all we define $\pi$ to be $\pi=2\sup\{t\geq 0 :\; \text{for}\; 0\leq s \leq t, \Re(e^{is})\geq 0 \; \text{and}\;  \Im(e^{is})\geq 0\}$ And we know that $e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}=i$,$e^{\pi i}=-1$ and $e^{2\pi i}=1$. The hint suggests finding the first positive zero of $\Re(e^{ix})$.

I have gotten something promising by taking the first two terms of the cosine (real) portion of the power series representation of $e^{ix}$ and setting it equal to $-1$ and solving for x, since this is should be a reasonable estimate of where the real
$\begin{equation}
1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}=-1\Rightarrow x=2\sqrt{2}
\end{equation}
$
Which is a decent lower bound (although I am also not so sure how to prove this is a lower bound, the next term is clearly going to add something but of course cos oscillates) but it is not as sharp a bound as I need. Playing around with the first few terms of the power series for both sine and cosine hasn't given me quite the bounds I want, and also I am not sure how to proceed proving that say, they are "local" maxes or min's of the exponential.

edit: I do not understand why this is on hold as I have given everything I was given by the instructor. The problem is in the title. The givens and the hint are provided in the first paragraph.

Comment: I cannot even understand the firsl line. What is the supremum of a set of complex numbers?

Comment: oops sorry, typo edited above

Comment: You can show that $1-x^2/2<\cos(x)<1-x^2/2+x^4/4$ between $0$ and $3\pi/4$ by straight study of the variations.

Comment: What is a study of the variations?

Comment: Some of the original context of this exercise would be needed to make it crystal clear.  I suspect that the point is related to inscribed and circumscribed regular polygons for the unit circle in the complex plane.  For example, the lower bound amounts to using the sixth roots of unity as corners of a regular hexagon and noting its perimeter gives us a lower bound on the unit circle's circumference.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by original context; perhaps it would be helpful to know that we just defined sin and cosine for the complex numbers and we have shown that every complex number can be written in polar form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call that set $S$. Notice that $S$ has the property that $x\in S\Rightarrow\forall y$ such that $0<y<x$, $y\in S$ (downward closure). To prove that $3<\pi$ you need to prove that $3/2\in S$, which establishes that it is a lower bound because $\pi$ is defined via a sup. To prove that $2\sqrt{3}$ is an upper bound, you need to prove that $\sqrt{3}$ is not in $S$. This can be done by direct computation ($1-3/2=-1/2$ and the alternating error bound gives $\pm 3/8$ so the value of the real part falls below zero). Since $S$ is downwards closed, that forces it to be an upper bound.

Comment: $1-3/2+9/4!=-1/8$. Yes you can also use a two-term approximation as well.

Comment: Yes, I see what you did now. I was using alternating series error, you were using Lagrange error.

Comment: No, I was using alternating. $27/6!=3/80$ is the absolute value of the next term

Comment: Ah, you were using alternating in a slightly strange way: after taking three terms, what you have is *already* larger than the desired quantity (because the next term is negative), and yet you wanted to use it to construct an upper bound. So there was no need to consider the fourth term at all.

Comment: Eh true. Hadn't thought about that.

Comment: Nice approach by the way.